# Putting element into HashMap with Map interface

Tags: java, dictionary, kotlin

I'm trying Kotlin and I've encountered a small problem that I can't resolve.
When I have the following construction I can put elements into the map:

```
val map = HashMap<String, String>()
map["asd"] = "s"
map.put("34", "354")
```

However when I create a map with the `Map` interface I can only read them, what I'm doing wrong ?

```
val map: Map<String, String> = HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("24", "34") //error
map["23"] = "23" //error
```

Or maybe I'm confusing something about interfaces in Kotlin ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In the first example map gets the type of HashMap,
in the second example you cast it to the Interface Map.

Map is a readonly map, there is no put/set, see [here](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-map/index.html)

In order to be able to edit the map, you should use [MutableMap](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-mutable-map/index.html)

Comment: Coming from Java, it's important to remember that Map is not coming from java.util.Map but from Map defined in Collections.kt. 

As a Kotlin newbie, I've been caught out by this as well.  As mentioned above Map is readonly; to change the map use MutableMap.  There's also helper methods to create different maps in Maps.kt i.e. hashMapOf etc

Answer (score 0):

When working with kotlin collections, one important consideration is that, kotlin categorizes its collections as mutable and immutable. this is in contrast to java, where no such categorization exists.

In kotlin for most collections you have a base interface which only supports read-only methods. In your case [`Map<K,V`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/) is an example of that, from the docs

> Methods in this interface support only read-only access to the map;
> read-write access is supported through the MutableMap interface.

this is the reason for error when you try to modify the map after `val map: Map<String, String> = HashMap<String, String>();`, even though the actual object is of type `HashMap<String,String>`, but the `map` reference is of type `Map<String,String>`, which will only provide read only operation.

Now if you use a class which implements [`MutableMap<K,V>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-map/#kotlin.collections.MutableMap) then you can put values in map as well. this is the case with `val map = HashMap<String, String>()`, since here type of `map` is [`HashMap<K,V>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-hash-map/), which extends `MutableMap<K,V>` and hence is mutable.